# Email responsive : media queries doesn't work

Tags: email, media-queries

I work on my first email responsive. So I add some rules on mobile, but none walk :(

I conducted several test Litnus, simulation, media queries work perfectly on mobile.

Instead of displaying my long code, here is the HTML file : http://1x9bsxt890.1fichier.com/

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Some email clients still don't accept media queries.

Comment: Hello :) I know, but for example, iPhone accept the @media. And in my test, 0 smartphone accept my media queries :(